# The LPP below is getting min ratios to be zero or undefined, what do I do?

Tags: operations-research

Z = 2X1 + 3X2 + 10X3
subject to
x1 + 2x3 = 0
x2 + x3 = 1
x1,x2,x3 >= 0

I tried using Artificial Variables and converted into standard LPP but during the 2nd iteration all the min ratios were undefined and zero.

Answer (score 0):

We can analyze, simplify, and solve this LPP as follows. If $x_1, x_3\ge 0$ and $x_1+2x_3=0$ then both $x_1$ and $x_3$ are zeroes. Then $x_2=1$ and so $z=3$.